# How to find maximum subarray sum using divide and conquer, returned as an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, divide-and-conquer, sub-array

Currently I am having an issue with maximum subarray sum question. I'm trying to figure out how to, instead of using the commented code, where it puts the values in `LRMax`. Where `LRMax[0]` is the left index of the maxsub array, `LRMax[1]` is the right index of the maxsub array and `LRMax[2]` is the sum of the maxsub array.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {0, 13, -3, -25, 20, -3, -16, -23, 18, 20, -7, 12, -5,
                -22, 15, -4, 7};
        int low = 1; int high = 16; int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        int[] LRMax = new int[3];

        LRMax = maxSubarray(values, low, high);
        System.out.println(LRMax[0] + " " + LRMax[1] + " " +LRMax[2]);
    }

    public static int[] maxSubarray(int[] values, int low, int high) {   //returns LRMax: LRMax[0 and 1] -> left and right index of max subarray
        //        and LRMax[2] -> the crossing sub array's sum
        int[] LRMax = new int[3];
        //If the array contains one element, set all of LRMax to low.
        if (high == low) {
            LRMax[0] = 0;
            LRMax[1] = 0;
            LRMax[2] = low;
            return LRMax;
        }

        //Find midpoint of the array
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        //Find maximum subarray sum for left subarray including middle element
        int leftMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = mid; i >= low; i--) {
            sum += values[i];
            if (sum > leftMax) {
                leftMax = sum;
            }
        }

        //Find maximum subarray sum for right subarray but not including middle element
        int rightMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = mid + 1; i <= high; i++) {
            sum += values[i];
            if (sum > rightMax) {
                rightMax = sum;
            }
        }

        //Find maximum subarray sum for the left and right subarray, take maximum value
        //int maxLeftRight = Integer.max(maxSubarray(values, low, mid), maxSubarray(values, mid + 1, high));

        // return the maximum of the three
        //return Integer.max(maxLeftRight, leftMax + rightMax)
        LRMax[0] = ;
        LRMax[1] = ;
        LRMax[2] = ;

        return LRMax;
    }
}
```

Comment: `LRMax[0] = ;` isn't valid Java. Beyond that, what's the actual issue you're experiencing?

Comment: @AndyTurner I know it isn't. I'm trying to have LRMax[0], LRMax[1] and LRMax[2] save the left index of the maxsub array, right index of the maxsub array and the sum of the maxsub array but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: When you find that `sum > leftMax` is true, record the value of `i` at the same time. Similarly for `sum > rightMax`.

Comment: @AndyTurner what would I do for int maxLeftRight? since maxSubarray is a int[]

Comment: `maxLeftRight` is in commented code. I don't know what you should do, sorry.